# Silverlight: WebContext is not available exception crashes visual studio

Tags: c#, silverlight, authentication, prism, wcf-ria-services

I have a prism app using RIA services, and my authentication service is in a separate RIA class library.

The program works fine at runtime. Authentication and all.

I am getting a nasty error at design time, though, which crashes both visual studio and blend. Blend will crash immediately when I open the solution. Visual studio will crash when I close the particular view (page). At least blend gave me a crash log after though. The error has to do with me setting an instance of my viewmodel as the datacontext of the view in xaml rather than setting/injecting one at runtime.

So when setting a viewmodel datacontext at runtime, the viewmodel constructor is called when the view is loaded in the designer. And when the view is closed the destructor is called. That is where I am getting the exception that crashes vs/blend. So here is the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The current instance of WebContext
>   is not available.  You must instantiate a WebContext and add it to
>   Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects within the default App
>   constructor.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.WebContextBase.get_Current()
>   at MyClassLibrary.WebContext.get_Current()     at
>   MyShellProject.ShellViewModel.Finalize()

It's odd because I am instantiating a WebContext in my App constructor. And there are no problems at runtime. Only since I added an instance of my viewmodel as the datacontext I get the crash at runtime.

So in my App.xaml I have:

```
<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <MyClassLibrary:WebContext>
            <MyClassLibrary:WebContext.Authentication>
                <ApplicationServices:FormsAuthentication>
                    <ApplicationServices:FormsAuthentication.DomainContext>
                        <MyClassLibrary_Web:MyAuthenticationContext />
                    </ApplicationServices:FormsAuthentication.DomainContext>
                </ApplicationServices:FormsAuthentication>
            </MyClassLibrary:WebContext.Authentication>
        </MyClassLibrary:WebContext>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

I did also try the code behind equivalent of this in the App constructor. Both have the same result.

This blog post has a little more detail about how my project is set up: http://avcode.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/authenticaion-prism-wcf-ria-services/

Anyone have a clue as to why at design time, visual studio is not aware that I have instantiated a WebContext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the following variable in ViewModel:

```
public bool IsDesignTime
{
  get
  {
    return DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(Application.Current.RootVisual);
  }
}
```

You can wrap the piece of code which tries to instantiate the WebContext at design time using this variable's value and return a Mocked object instead. I think WebContext is instantiated when the App is running and connected, not sure though. Late reply but may be useful to someone.

Comment: I always continued to get crashes. But yes, detecting design time seemed to be the right direction. Even though I had wrapped my accessor property with design time detection I still got the crash. I could never figure out how else it was getting accessed during design time, but there must have been something behind the scenes. Either way, my days of silverlight are over so it's irrelevant.

Comment: This is the right answer, although you can simplify things and just use `DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool`.  Attach another instance of Visual Studio to the instance running your Silverlight project and keep reloading the failing page(s) until you find all locations that reference WebContext (refer to stack traces).  More details can be found in [this bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/574316/webcontext-not-available).